# ¿Cómo sumar ciertas filas de un DataFrame con cierta lógica? - R

Tags: r

Quiero sumar la columna `personas` por `id`, y dependiendo de una variable controlable que es:

Me gustaría sumar sólo a la gente durante el invierno, es decir cuando el mes es *12, 1 o 2*, y para cada `id` específico:

```
         id     mes    personas
1       199     1       2
2       199     2       3
3       199     3       266504
4       199     4       177196
5       199     5       263066
6       199     6       266504
7       199     7       177196
8       199     8       263066
9       199     9       266504
10      199     10       177196
11      199     11       3
12      199     12       4
13        4     1        9
14        4     2        2
15        4     3       266504
16        4     4       177196
17        4     5       263066
18        4     6       266504
19        4     7       177196
20        4     8       263066
21        4     9       266504
22        4     10      177196
23        4     11      1333
24        4     12      3
25       57     1       4
26       57     2       4
27       57     3       266504
28       57     4       177196
29       57     5       263066
30       57     6       266504
31       57     7       177196
32       57     8       263066
33       57     9       266504
34       57     10      177196
35       57     11      4444
36       57     12      4
```

El resultado que quiero es un nuevo *DataFrame*:

```
         id     person_invierno  
1       199          9
2        4          14
3       57          12
```

He intentado `ddply` sin éxito.

Comment: Esto es Stackoverflow en español. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta será retirada. Para preguntar en ingles tiene SO

Comment: En lugar de ddply, intenta con el paquete `dplyr`: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En función de tu ejemplo, se me ocurre hacer algo así:

```
aggregate(personas ~ id, df[df$mes %in% c(1,2,12),], sum)
```

Reproduciendo tu ejemplo:

```
list <- "id,mes,personas
199,1,2
199,2,263066
199,3,266504
199,4,177196
199,5,263066
199,6,266504
199,7,177196
199,8,263066
199,9,266504
199,10,177196
199,11,3
199,12,4
4,1,9
4,2,2
4,3,266504
4,4,177196
4,5,263066
4,6,266504
4,7,177196
4,8,263066
4,9,266504
4,10,177196
4,11,1333
4,12,3
57,1,4
57,2,4
57,3,266504
57,4,177196
57,5,263066
57,6,266504
57,7,177196
57,8,263066
57,9,266504
57,10,177196
57,11,4444
57,12,4"

df = as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection(list), header=TRUE, sep=','))

aggregate(personas ~ id, df[df$mes %in% c(1,2,12),], sum)
```

Los datos de ejemplo no coinciden con la salida propuesta, por que el id 199 del mes 2 es 263066

```
   id personas
1   4       14
2  57       12
3 199   263072
```

La explicación: en primer lugar filtramos los datos del mes 12,1,2 mediante `df[df$mes %in% c(1,2,12),]` y luego agrupamos por `id` y aplicamos la función `sum` mediante `aggregate(personas ~ id, df[df$mes %in% c(1,2,12),], sum)`

Comment: Muchas gracias!! eso necesitaba:)